# How to stop playing flash object from javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

Is there a way to stop (destroy) a flash swf media file from playing. I want to stop playing a swf with sound in it after popup closed, but it just wont die in IE8 and keeps playing in background.

Comment: Not too specific description...please provide more. If the swf is in a real window popup, it should stop after closing it. Or maybe you open it in a javascript&DOM 'popup' (lightbox for example), and after closing, the DOM element only hidden and not removed correctly (with javascript)?

Comment: Its a DOM ExtJS ToolTip control that contains an <object> with flash media to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no access to Flash functionality from DOM, unless it explicitly exported through ExternalInterface.

Comment: But you can from javascript, if external interfaces are specified for this purpose in the actionscript.

Comment: what about removing the <object></object> from dom or hiding it.. does it have any deterministic effect? 

@pinusnegra - is this a standard api or your custom AS methods exposed in js?

Comment: If you remove it, it should stop, hiding doesnt work (the object is still there)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the swf object from the DOM.